# Vim Terminal interferes with statusline

Tags: terminal, statusline

I am editing a lot of files with Vim, and I have the following in my `.vimrc` to help me stay oriented as to which file I am in:

```
" Add file name to statusline so we know where we are in the slideshow
set statusline+=%f
```

I recently started using [mdless](https://github.com/ttscoff/mdless/) to render the Markdown files in Vim Terminal (`:terminal`); it's working great except Terminal overwrites my statusline setting. Is there way to keep Terminal's paws off the statusline?  :)

The built-in help on Terminal says:

> In Terminal-Normal mode the statusline and window title show "(Terminal)".  If
> the job ends while in Terminal-Normal mode this changes to
> "(Terminal-finished)".

It's hard to believe this isn't configurable... just about everything else is.  :)

---

### How to reproduce

Given a file `vimrc` with the following content:

```
" Make status line visible
set laststatus=2
" Add file name to statusline so we know where we are in the slideshow
set statusline+=%f
```

Start `vim` using this vimrc:

```
vim -u vimrc vimrc
```

and it will show "vimrc" on a status line, on 2nd line from the bottom.

Now run:

```
:term++curwin cat vimrc
```

and that changes that 2nd line from the bottom to say

```
!cat vimrc [finished]
```

Also its color changes, from white to green.

Comment: I assume you are talking about `:terminal` when you say “Vim Terminal”?

Comment: Yes, quite right.

Comment: I can't really reproduce it... The status line in the terminal is different and doesn't really obbey the `'statusline'` setting, but I don't see the value of `'statusline'` actually changing when `:terminal` is executed. Can you provide more details on what you're seeing?

Comment: Or do you mean that you would like to override what the status line shows for a `:terminal` window and `'statusline'` doesn't actually do that? Are you looking for a way to configure what the status line shows there, is that it?

Comment: I added a "How to reproduce" section @filbranden Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just normal. `%f` stands for current buffer's name (`:h bufname()`) and it gets inserted as is, i.e. `!cat vimrc`, plus status, i.e. `[finished]`.

To change terminal's buffer name

```
 call term_start('cat vimrc', {'term_name': 'foobar'})
```

To setup status line for terminal windows only

```
augroup test | au!
    autocmd TerminalWinOpen * setlocal statusline=foobar
augroup end
```

The colors are also per default. For regular buffers it's `StatusLine/StatusLineNC`, and for terminal buffers - `StatusLineTerm/StatusLineTermNC`.

To change your colorscheme

```
colorscheme foobar
```

To change individual highlighting group settings

```
augroup test | au!
    autocmd ColorScheme * hi! link StatusLineTerm StatusLine
    autocmd ColorScheme * hi! link StatusLineTermNC StatusLineNC
augroup end
```

To overwrite highlighting group by status line

```
set statusline=%#StatusLine#%f
```